# My code is skipping the View and going into controller directly. ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**My view**

```
<h1>Return a Book</h1>
<%= form_tag("/orders/returnB", method: "get") do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :ID, "ID" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :ID, nil, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

**My controller**

```
def returnB
  getid = params[:ID]
  @order = Order.find(getid)
  @order.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'Order was destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

its just going directly to the controller and as my controller could not get the id so it give an error. So i am doing this in my route:

`get 'orders/return' => 'orders#returnB'`

Comment: What do you mean it's "going directly to the controller"? Everything goes to the controller first. What URL are you hitting? What does your routing look like? I'd also strongly consider sticking with normal parameter naming conventions. And indenting properly.

Comment: That is because you have routed it to go to the controller's `returnB` method.  Rails will always hit the controller first.  You shouldn't be using a get request to destroy an order either.  Can you explain what functionality you're trying to achieve?  You want to display the view, then the user fills out the form and on submission the Order gets destroyed?

Comment: in view you mention method: :get and in controller doing some destroy operation

Comment: And then giving an error id not found?

Comment: Ya because i am getting the ID from the view and then i find that order with that ID and then destroy it.

Comment: @j-dexx  yes you are right. What should i do I want the same thing you mention in last line.

Comment: What is your view file named? `app/views/orders/returnB`?

Comment: app/views/orders/returnB.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

In a simple rails flow the request first hits the controller and then the view template, with same name as of controller's, is rendered.

I think you have your form defined in

```
view/orders/returnB.erb
```

That's why the request is hitting the controller first before rendering the form. I suggest you moving the form into some other view template.

Comment: Where should i place it otherwise. It will give error of missing template.

Comment: You can prevent the default behaviour by redirecting the flow to a different controller or specifying a render path of a different view template. Can you please describe in detail what you are trying to achieve here? And what other view templates you have in your view directory?

Answer (score 0):

Change your routes to:

```
delete 'orders/return' => 'orders#return_order'
```

**delete** should be used to destroy.

Change form to:

```
<h1>Return a Book</h1>
<%= form_tag("/orders/return", method: "delete") do %>
 <div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag :ID, "ID" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :ID, nil, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
<%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Change action name from `returnB` to `return_order` as it is not the right convention to write a method name.

Change controller code to:

```
def return_order
  @order = Order.find_by_id(params[:ID])
  @order.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'Order was destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Comment: please post your stack trace.

Comment: `return` is a reserved words. I am not sure if you can use it to define a method.
http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words